# How to return array stored in parse user class

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How do I return an array that I added in my Parse User class?
the array has 2 names in it

```
var user = PFUser()
var friends: AnyObject! = user["friends"]
println(friends)
return friends.length
```

that returns null

Comment: return from where? this should be a method or a computed property to have a return any object. Is it your full code ?

Comment: I'm not aware of swift, but in Objective-C you can retrieve current user's data by: `[[PFUser currentuser] objectForKey:"<column name>"];`

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus no, the return part isnt the part thats erroring, thats just to show what i do with it after, no its not the full code. the error comes on line 2

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. if let friends = user["friends"] { println(friends) }

Comment: I just got it working, it is supposed to be:

Comment: var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    var friends: AnyObject! = user["friends"];

Comment: @user3673262: You should make that an answer, not a comment.